# Can not change template of ContentControl from style's datatrigger - datatrigger not firing

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hello WPF aficionados,

I have a content control inside a user control that sets it data context to the selected item of a listview inside the same usercontrol.  The selected item property on the view model is called **Selection**.

Here is the content control's declaration:

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Selection}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Template"  Value="{StaticResource JobSnapShotProgDetail}"/>                            
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bTandM}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource JobSnapShotProgDetail}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bTandM}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource JobSnapShotTM_Detail}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>                        
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

The Templates are defined as ControlTemplates in another resource file like:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="JobSnapShotProgDetail" >
     ...
 </ControlTemplate >
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="JobSnapShotTM_Detail" >
     ...
 </ControlTemplate >
```

The binding works great meaning that the template's fields all display the correct data from the Selection object.

### My Problem:

I want the content control to use one of two different control templates based on the value of the Selection's bTandM property.

### What happens now:

When I change the selection of the listview, which changes the **Selection** object, the template IS NOT being changed based on the value of the **Selection's** bTandM property (a sql server bit data type).  Yes the **Selection** object implements iNotifyPropertyChanged, and the ControlTemplate's fields that bind to the **Selection's** properties all display the correct data without any binding errors in the output window.

### What I Tried:

It seems like the datatrigger is not getting "HIT" by the code.  I tried to break the datatrigger by adding foo instead of a number which should have not been able to convert, but no error is generated. ie:

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bTandM}" Value="foo">
```

This leads me to believe that the trigger is not firing for some reason.

### Question:

Can someone help me figure out why this data trigger has no effect.

Thanks in advance

JK

---

### EDIT 1:

I tried to use a technique found [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/211113/MVVM-Friendly-DataTemplate-switching), but it also does not work.  THe data triggers are not getting fired.

New attempt using DataTemplate with DataTriggers that target a contentcontrol's template property:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectionCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl x:Name="DetailControl" Template="{DynamicResource JobSnapShotProgDetail}" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bTandM}" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="DetailControl" Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource JobSnapShotProgDetail}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bTandM}" Value="1">
                    <Setter TargetName="DetailControl" Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource JobSnapShotTM_Detail}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Again, the template loads fine and the properties are display correctly for the initial template set in the style setter, but the templates do not change based on the object's bTandM boolean property.

Comment: it seems correct... just a stupid question.. are you raising PropertyChanged for `Selection` property from your VM properly?

Comment: Could you try using ContentTemplate rather than Template?

Comment: @nit yes PropertyChanged is used and working because other UI updates that depend on this are working

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer, I can not use contentTemplate because I get a conversion error in the style setter: 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.ContentTemplate' property on a Setter.

Comment: @JKing, You need to use a DataTemplate rather than a ControlTemplate

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer, thanks for the reply but I need some clarity.  Data template is not a property of ContentControl.  I tried this solution with data templates but could not get it to work.

Comment: @nit, So you were right, but it was not the PropertyChanged for the Selection that was the problem.  I needed to Notify the Change for the Selection.bTandM.  See my answer below for full reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so this turned out to be an issue with NotifyPropertyChanged.

The selection property of my viewmodel **does** implement INPC but the problem was that the underlying class type *(**vw_Job_Snapshot** which is a mapped entity from a sql server view)* of selection did not.

I had to implement iNPC in the underlying class and then in my viewmodel use the Property Setter for the Selection Property to also notify the specific bTandM property change like so:

```
    Public Property Selection As vw_Job_Snapshot
        Get
            Return Me._Selection
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As vw_Job_Snapshot)
            Me._Selection = value

            ''Notify of specific property changed
            value.OnPropertyChanged("bTandM")

            _Selection = value
            RaisePropertyChanged(JobSnapshotSelectedPropertyName)
        End Set
    End Property
```

After this the following code in my view worked perfectly:

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Selection}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Template"  Value="{DynamicResource JobSnapShotTM_Detail}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bTandM}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource JobSnapShotProgDetail}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bTandM}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource JobSnapShotTM_Detail}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Thanks to everyone who helped

Comment: Well now I feel sheepish. Was looking at a similar problem and had to fix a similar change notification bug. Should have checked that without a google search prompting me to. lol.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Your selector would look something like this (I'm assuming your class is called JobSnapShot):

```
public class JobSnapShotDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is JobSnapShot)
        {
            JobSnapShot jobSnapShot = item as JobSnapShot;

            if (jobSnapShot.bTandM == 1)
                return
                    element.FindResource("JobSnapShotProgDetail") as DataTemplate;
            else
                return
                    element.FindResource("JobSnapShotTM_Detail") as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:JobSnapShotDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myDataTemplateSelector"/>
</Window.Resources>



<ContentControl ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}" .... />
```

Comment: Thanks Eirik, I was hoping to avoid the DataTemplateSelector as I am using MVVM and it would complicate the view viewmodel relationship.  I know this works and might have to end up using it but I was hoping for a "pure" xaml solution.